# How to filter Object from Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I have 2 or more objects in Main Object.
How can I find one object againt this key value.

```js
{
    "0": {
        "component": "AWAY",
        "currentUser": {
            "id": 1,
            "userName": "abc",
            "inRoom": false,
            "image": ""
        },
    },
    "1": {
        "component": "PHONE_BOTH",
        "currentUser": {
            "id": 1,
            "userName": "abc",
            "inRoom": false,
            "image": ""
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "component": "MEETING_ROOM",
        "currentUser": {
            "id": 1,
            "userName": "abc",
            "inRoom": true,
            "image": ""
        }
    }
}
```

I just want to get one object where inRoom = true

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Also no need to index an object with numeric keys. Use an array instead then you can use filter directly on the array

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to index an object with numeric keys. Use an array instead then you can use filter directly on the array

```js
const arr = [{
    "component": "AWAY",
    "currentUser": {
      "id": 1,
      "userName": "abc",
      "inRoom": false,
      "image": ""
    },
  },
  {
    "component": "PHONE_BOTH",
    "currentUser": {
      "id": 1,
      "userName": "abc",
      "inRoom": false,
      "image": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "component": "MEETING_ROOM",
    "currentUser": {
      "id": 1,
      "userName": "abc",
      "inRoom": true,
      "image": ""
    }
  }
]
console.log(arr.filter(({currentUser}) => currentUser.inRoom === true))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your dictionary to an array and then find the object by a specific criteria using the `find()` array method. See implementation:

```js
// usersDict is the given Main Object

// convert usersDict to array of user objects
let usersArray = Object.values(usersDict);

// find user which has inRoom flag true
let userInRoom = usersArray.find(o => !!o.currentUser.inRoom);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var bb = {
        "0": {
            "component": "AWAY",
            "currentUser": {
                "id": 1,
                "userName": "abc",
                "inRoom": false,
                "image": ""
            },
        },
        "1": {
            "component": "PHONE_BOTH",
            "currentUser": {
                "id": 1,
                "userName": "abc",
                "inRoom": false,
                "image": ""
            }
        },
        "2": {
            "component": "MEETING_ROOM",
            "currentUser": {
                "id": 1,
                "userName": "abc",
                "inRoom": true,
                "image": ""
            }
        }
    }
    
    var kk = []
    for (const man in bb) {
      if(bb[man].currentUser.inRoom){
          kk.push({man: bb[man]})
      }
    }

console.log(kk.length ? kk[0] : {})
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should convert your object to an array then use the `filter` method in the array:

```
// obj = your data
Object.values(obj).filter(obj => obj.currentUser.inRoom)
```